# How to fix Eslint error "prefer-destructuring"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I wanted to shorten an object literal in ES6 like this:

```
const loc = this.props.local;
```

The reason is `loc.foo();` is a lot easier to type than `this.props.local.foo();`

But now ESLint complains:

> Use object destructuring: prefer-destructuring

I've read the [error description on eslint.org](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) but I don't understand it. They have an example which looks very similar to my code but theirs seem to be ok?

```
var foo = object.bar;
```

How can I fix the error without setting it to ignore in the `.eslintrc` file?

Comment: That's a rule one needs to *enable* in the first place. Why did you do that if you don't like it?

Comment: That's not true. If one extends someone else's config, then you might have to disable this rule instead.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using Airbnb styleguide

Comment: Full explanation here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring

Answer (score 109, accepted):

change your code from:

```
const local = this.props.local;
```

to:

```
const { local } = this.props;
```

They are equivalent and you can call `local.foo()` in the same way. except that the second use object destructuring.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I wonder why Airbnb styleguide thinks this is important. Imho it makes things just more complicated.

Comment: It's an ES6 feature used to unpack variables from arrays or objects. this syntax create an array from variables: `var x = [y, z]` . destructuring assignment uses similar syntax, but on the left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable. var [y, z]  = x. same thing is true for objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. That's it!

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense for extracting multiple values but not for a single one. Airbnb styleguide is a bit to strict at this point imho.

Comment: There is a typo here "lacal" should be "local"

Comment: @BadisMerabet Awsome :)

Comment: @BadisMerabet can you help with the redefining case ?:
```
let subdomain = {};
if (isBlank) {
  subdomain = object.property;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to auto-fix this error with some eslint plugin(s)?

Answer (score 7):

It's a new construct in ES 6 that allows you to match property of an object in assignment. The syntax you need is:

```
const { local: loc } = this.props
```

which translates to: "declare a constant loc and assign it the value of property local from this.props".

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you to use

```
const {props: {local: loc}} = this;
```

Comment: This is so much uglier and confusing than just accessing a property normally.

Comment: @MartinDawson I agree, but you need to tell that the person who enabled their linter's `prefer-destructuring` rule :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'd prefer to tell the person that even added that rule to the linter. Destructuring only makes sense to me when assigning to multiple variables at a time as it reduces repetition. Is there a way to only have the rule emit an error when it detects multiple consecutive declarations / assignments from the same object?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There's also repetition that can be avoided when variable name and property key are the same. To avoid the rule when this is not the case(as in this question), you seem to be able to turn `enforceForRenamedProperties` off. I don't know a setting that only enforces destructuring when there are multiple targets, you might want to file an issue for that.

Comment: The more I use eslint, the more I realise a ton of rules doesn't mean more clarity