# prefer-destructuring fix not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

Related to: [How to fix Eslint error "prefer-destructuring"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395070/how-to-fix-eslint-error-prefer-destructuring).

I Have:

```
method (v100) => {
    let L,
        H;
    if (v100 <= 70) {
        const obj = {L: 1, H: 2};
        L = obj.L;
        H = obj.H;
    } else {
        L = ((0.8353 * (v100 ** 2)) + (14.67 * v100)) - 216;
        H = ((0.1684 * (v100 ** 2)) + (11.85 * v100)) - 97;
    }
    return ((L - 40) / (L - H)) * 100
}
```

and changed it to

```
{ L } = obj;
{ H } = obj;
```

as written in the answer. But now I get an Unexpected token error.

It should also be possible to write it like this, right?:

```
{ L, H } = obj;
```

Comment: As stated, it throws an unexpected token error

Comment: Try `({ L, H } = obj);` to not treat curly braces as blocks.

Comment: @destoryer this fixed it, thank you! Add it as an answer with a little more explanation and I'll accept and upvote

Comment: @31piy added more code to make the error reproducible

Comment: I'm confused by your code. If `v100 > 70`, you're going to return `((undefined - 40) / (undefined - undefined)) * 100`. Did you omit a bunch of code to post here?

Comment: @mccambridge yes I omitted the else. Wait a second, I'll add it too.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, I repeated @destoryer 's suggestion. Since you don't have a `var/let/const` keyword, it's trying to treat your curlies as an object or block.

Comment: I would really recommend using `const obj = {L: 1, H: 2}; const {L, H} = v100 <= 70 ? obj : {L: 0.8353 * v100**2 + 14.67 * v100 - 216, H: 0.1684 * v100**2 + 11.85 * v100 - 97};` for simplicity

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your response but due to readability issues we also have no-ternary in use. Also, I'd say this isn't exactly a dupe as the question differs from the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
({ L, H } = obj);
```

Quoting from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The round braces `( ... )` around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is var `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> NOTE: Your `( ... )` expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.