# How to define array's length without length property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've recently came across this particular code:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
const { length } = arr;
for (i = 0; i<=length; i++){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Apparently this (`const { length } = arr;`) somehow works, but I haven't found any information on the Internet on either how or why should this actually work.

**My question**: how does this { } construction work and why doesn't it work when I change `{ length }` to anything else, like `{ arrlength }`? Can we possibly use this construction with other array's properties and how?

Comment: This is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `const { length } = arr` is equivalent to `const length = arr.length`

Comment: While that works, that's really weird.  `i <= arr.length` works just find without an extra variable

Comment: @Dan so we can define array's length by simply assigning array to an empty variable?

Comment: No the variable name should be `length`

Comment: Why can't we use another `const` name though, I'm really confused))

Comment: This is an example of code being "too fancy".  There are more concise ways to do this.  Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: See also [Javascript object bracket notation ({ Navigation } =) on left side of assign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26999820/215552), my preferred canonical when the user doesn't know about destructuring.

Comment: Because `const { arrlength } = arr` is equivalent to `const arrlength = arr.arrlength`. If you want to create a varaible that is different to the property name, you need to use `const { length: arrlength } = arr` Please go through duplicates and the link added by @Dan in the first comment

Comment: Ooh, thank you @adiga

Comment: the destructuring assignment is *not* defining the arrays length. the arrays length is determined by the array literal. all the assignment is doing is creating a variable named length which has the value of `array.length` assigned to it at time of assignment.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this until now

Comment: @Taplar Airbnb styleguide forces this [How to fix Eslint error “prefer-destructuring”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395070)

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` you don't need an extra variable at all

Comment: @Taplar valid point